# How do I make the router send an email every time the password changes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, email, passwords

I have two routers at home. One is TP Link (to share connections with neighbors) and the other is ZTE F609 (from ISP). I want to hack my ZTE router.

My brother is very naughty, he often changes ZTE router passwords to work on me. This makes me feel annoyed every time I get home and can't access the internet.

What I want to do is how do I always get notifications via email every time there is a password change on my ZTE router. Can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to hack it? Reset it back to defaults, make a new administrative password. And set the wpa2-psk to whatever you like.

Comment: Set new, complex, password. Do not tell it to your brother - he don't need it to access Internet. If need, create additional account with view settings/logs only rights and without password or with simple one - it's enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t have to hack your router. You can solve this problem as Tim said.

1. Press the `button circled` in the following picture until the power indicator goes off and then illuminate again. 
   [image]
2. Then you can use the **initial administrator account and password** to login in to the router setting page.
3. In general, you can see the **initial administrator account and password** on the back of the router or in the Instruction manually.
4. After entering the account number and password, you can `reset` the **administrator password** and **WiFi password**.
5. After that, you can put the **initial administrator account and password** in a place that your brother doesn't know, so that he can't reset the router's password again.